Importing external packages in Java
I'm trying to import the jbox2d package with import org.jbox2d.*; to my Java project (not a Maven project). I cloned the jbox2d package with the command - git clone https://github.com/jbox2d/jbox2d. I then imported this as a Maven Project.
The test-bed is working fine (even changes to the code are reflected when the app is run). But when I try to import the package in my project (again, using import org.jbox2d.*;), the editor says 'import cannot be resolved'.
I added the directory with the jbox2d package to my CLASSPATH system variable, as the solution in this post suggested, still no luck.
Is there something else I should be doing?
For more info - I'm on Windows 10, using Eclipse IDE.
Found a fix - When I tried to create new Vec2 object (this is in the jbox2d package), one of the fixes suggested by the editor was to 'Configure Build Path'. Selecting that seems to work fine, as I'm able to import the jbox2d package into my project. I'll keep the question open for now as I still don't think this is the right approach and there could be better ways of doing this. Moreover, I still need a better understanding of why I had to configure build path. I thought setting the CLASSPATH with the directory of the package would be sufficient.

(1)  If you want to use source to compile, have you executed mvn clean package install to install jbox2d on your local machine? (2) Assume that your project is Maven architecture. You only need to add a reference to jbox2d under <dependencies> in your project's pom.xml. You can do this here (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact /org.jbox2d) Find the content you want to add: For example: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jbox2d/jbox2d-library/2.2.1.1 <dependency>  <groupId>org.jbox2d</groupId>  <artifactId>jbox2d-library</artifactId>  <version>2.2.1.1</version> </dependency>

Please describe it so that someone else can reproduce your problem. Do you want to use JBox2D as library in your own (Maven?) project (which would not require a Git clone) or do you want to make changes to JBox2D? It is unclear to me what you mean by "I added the directory with the package to my CLASSPATH system variable, still no luck." (that doesn't sound like the right thing in any case).

@life888888 to build and install the package mvn clean install is sufficent.. package install repeats several steps...

Just to use the dependency you can define a dependency in your pom file... which will download that from central repository (https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.jbox2d/jbox2d/versions) but I'm not sure if this is a good idea because that package is very old (11 years+) ?

@howlger, yes I want to use JBox2D as library in my own project. My project is just a plain Java project. I'm trying to import jbox2d with the command import org.jbox2d.*;. I'm not trying to make any changes to JBox2D. By "adding the directory with package to the CLASSPATH system variable", I was trying to follow the solution to this problem. Edited the original question for more clarity.

@khmarbaise, sorry I didn't make it clear earlier, my project is not a maven project, so there is no pom.xml.

Version 2.2.1.1 if you add the repository they use. Does that seem up to date?

Yeah, you'll get newer jbox2d-library-2.3.1-SNAPSHOT.jar if you build it yourself. Then you can run mvn install:install-file -Dfile=target/jbox2d-library-2.3.1-SNAPSHOT.jar on it

Ok, found a fix. When I tried to create new Vec2 object (this is in the jbox2d package), one of the fixes suggested by the editor was to 'Configure Build Path'. Selecting that seems to work fine, as I'm able to import the jbox2d package into my project. I'll keep the question open for now as I still don't think this is the right approach/there could be better ways of doing this. Regardless, thanks everyone who tried to help!

Well, of course if you wanted to allow others to build your project, then it's not really portable. The problem is that the devs don't seem to have updated the repositories recently. If you can live with 2.2.1.1 then I can give you the pom elements to allow that.

Under the hood, adding a jar to the Build Path with Configure Build Path in Eclipse is adding it to the classpath. Have a look at the contents of .classpath in the root of your Eclipse project.

You should either use a build system like Maven... if you don't do not configure in Eclipse because that makes a hurdle for others and also the hurdle to be reused by consumers of your project/lib... etc. On the other hand why have you tagged the question with Maven if it is not using a pom.xml file?
